# Creating an Excel Log File using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I'm trying to create an Excel log file using VBA. The idea is that I have columns named Tasks and By and every time a user inputs a certain task in the column cell, the cell next to it (the By column cell) would display his user name as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Excel sheet screenshot]

I have finished the application but every time I try to test it it gives me different results and none of these results are the intended so if some one would pay a look at the code I would be glad.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.EnableEvents = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False

Dim serialRange As Excel.Range

Set serialRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A200")

Dim taskRange As Excel.Range

Set taskRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B200")

For Each cell In serialRange

        Dim rownumber As Integer

        rownumber = ActiveCell.Row
        
        Dim cellValue As Integer
        
        cellValue = cell.Value

        If (ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "") Then
        
        cellValue = Null
        
        Else
        
        cellValue = rownumber - 1
        
        End If
        
Next
        
For Each cell In taskRange

        If (cell.Value = "") Then
        
        cell.Value = ""
        
        Else
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(2).Value = Environ("username")

        End If
        
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.EnableEvents = True

Application.CalculateBeforeSave = True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "none of the results are as intended" what exactly do you mean? Is there more than one sheet in the workbook? Using ActiveSheet can cause trouble

Answer (score 0):

couple of issues I see with the code:

1. The code only runs when workbook is opened. If that is by design then fine, I moved the code to Workbook_SheetCalculate to test it
2. Using ActiveCell and ActiveSheet can cause some real issues. For instance, when I test the code, it puts my UserName in the cell 2 cels down from whatever cell is active, not in the column next to the cell it is evaluating. This is due to the use of ActiveCell when you SHOULD be using cell and the offset should be (0,1) not (2)

> ```
> For Each cell In taskRange
>
>         If (cell.Value = "") Then
>              cell.Value = ""
>         Else
>              cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Environ("username")
>         End If
>         
> Next
> ```

3. You never turn calculation back to automatic (in the last section of your code, you set it to manual, which you did in the first part of your code)
4. Saving the workbook should occur after you re-enable all of the event handling

> ```
> Application.EnableEvents = true
> Application.ScreenUpdating = true
> Application.Calculation =xlCalculationAutomatic
> Application.CalculateBeforeSave = true
> ActiveWorkbook.Save
> ```

Comment: I'm new to vba to be honest so, regarding the workbook_open I tried to move the code to another method but didn't figure which. I'll try your code and see what I will get. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It gives a run time error 424 , object is required and the debbuger is pointing on the serial range line.